# inside contents of kinect SDK samples are missing when open them from kinect studio

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

Why are all samples for Kinect SDK 1.7 in Windows 7 missing?

Samples are there, but there is no Kinect file when I open them from Kinect Studio. The Path that I provide is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\Developer Toolkit v1.7.0\Samples\C#\KinectExplorer-WPF`.
Is there any problem with this version of the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use Kinect Studio to open those files.
According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855389.aspx):
`Kinect Studio is a tool that helps you record and play back depth and color streams from a Kinect. Use the tool to read and write data streams to help debug functionality, create repeatable scenarios for testing, and analyze performance.`

What you need to open C# files is called [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express).